# Resizing a GWT DockLayoutPanel's North/South/East/West components

Tags: gwt

Does anybody know how to resize a GWT DockLayoutPanel's child panels?  When I add a directional panel I have to give it a size ie:

```
panel.addSouth(new HTML("south"), 2);
```

How can I then resize this south panel after the fact?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `setWidgetSize` method like this:

```
DockLayoutPanel panel = new DockLayoutPanel(Style.Unit.EM);

HTML html = new HTML("south");
panel.addSouth(html, 2);

// change the size of the html widget to 4em
panel.setWidgetSize(html, 4);
```